# Why is my query not returning anything

Tags: c#, linq

I was writing a LINQ query to filter the records based on user input and selection. Some of the inputs may not be given from the user. So i need to filter based on the given input. I tried giving value for only 1 out of 5 optional inputs. But the query is not returning anything. Please help me to find the proper query. you can better understand after seeing the query.

**Code**

```
var model = (from items in Db.Items
             where ((items.ItemNo == null || 
                     items.ItemNo == String.Empty) ||
                    ((items.ItemNo.CompareTo(DD.FromItemNo) >= 0) &&
                     (items.ItemNo.CompareTo(DD.ToItemNo) <= 0))) &&
                   (items.InfoTypeId == 0 ||
                    (items.InfoTypeId == DD.InfoType)) &&
                   (items.CreatedOn == null ||
                    (items.CreatedOn >= DD.Start &&
                     items.CreatedOn <= DD.End)) &&
                   (items.StatusId == 0 ||
                    (items.StatusId == DD.Status)) &&
                   (items.LocationId == 0 ||
                    (items.LocationId == DD.Location)) &&
                   (items.CollectionId == 0 ||
                   (items.CollectionId == DD.Collection))
             select new ViewModel()
             {
                 Itemid = items.Id,
                 INo = items.ItemNo,
                 BTags = (from asd in Db.BibContents
                          where asd.BibId == items.BibId &&
                                asd.TagNo == "245" &&
                                asd.Sfld == "a"
                          select asd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Sid = (from stat in Db.ItemStatus1
                        where stat.Id == items.StatusId 
                        select stat.Description).FirstOrDefault(),

                 Option = DD.Option,
                 CurrItemNo = DD.ItemNumber
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, you've got a *huge* number of conditions in that `where` clause. I suggest you diagnose this by removing them all, then adding them back in one at a time.

Comment: For the First condition works fine. When including the 2nd condition without passing any data for the second condition fails to get the matching record for the first condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet what should he add as the first argument to where if all should be removed? I know that you use something like `1 == 1` in database language, but is there something similar for LINQ perhaps? (or should he just remove the `where` altogether)

Comment: @GertArnold You are right its working now. Also when DateTime field comes as null, then the parameter taking it as default value. But i dont want that. I need to stop taking default date value. Can you post an answer for this. so that i can mark it as answered.

Comment: @Dheyv: I would start off by getting rid fo the `where` clause to start with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to check the values of `DD` for `null`s or `0`s, not those of `items`:

```
var model = (from items in Db.Items
    where 
    (
       (DD.ItemNo == null || DD.ItemNo == String.Empty) 
       || (items.ItemNo.CompareTo(DD.FromItemNo) >= 0 && items.ItemNo.CompareTo(DD.ToItemNo) <= 0)
    ) 
    && (DD.InfoTypeId == 0 || (items.InfoTypeId == DD.InfoType)) 
    && (DD.CreatedOn == null || (items.CreatedOn >= DD.Start && items.CreatedOn <= DD.End)) 
    && (DD.StatusId == 0 || (items.StatusId == DD.Status))
    && (DD.LocationId == 0 || (items.LocationId == DD.Location)) 
    && (DD.CollectionId == 0 || (items.CollectionId == DD.Collection))
    select ...
```